# Why does my heroku app depend on will_paginate gem, which is not in my gemfile anymore?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Why does my heroku app depends on will_paginate gem, which is not in my gemfile anymore?

Hello,

I have a rails 3.2.11 application running on Heroku. Since my last successful deployment to Heroku I have locally:

- uninstalled the will_paginate gem and updated the Gemfile
- added the kaminari gem to the Gemfile
- replaced the will_paginate calls by kaminari ones
- some other changes...

Locally this application runs fine.

When I deploy this app (from git) to heroku, I get following exception in the logs:

```
» 12:47:45.667 2013-12-07 11:47:45.613491+00:00 heroku web.1 - - Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 31620 -e $RACK_ENV`
» 12:47:48.465 2013-12-07 11:47:48.410856+00:00 app web.1 - - => Booting Thin
» 12:47:48.564 2013-12-07 11:47:48.410856+00:00 app web.1 - - => Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:31620
» 12:47:48.564 2013-12-07 11:47:48.410856+00:00 app web.1 - - => Call with -d to detach
» 12:47:48.564 2013-12-07 11:47:48.410856+00:00 app web.1 - - => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
» 12:47:48.564 2013-12-07 11:47:48.410856+00:00 app web.1 - - Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
» 12:47:48.922 2013-12-07 11:47:48.860489+00:00 app web.1 - - Exiting
» 12:47:48.922 2013-12-07 11:47:48.861515+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- will_paginate (LoadError) from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing' from /app/config/environment.rb:41:in `<top (required)>' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require' from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize' from /app/config.ru:in `new' from /app/config.ru:in `<main>' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap' from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>' from script/rails:6:in `require' from script/rails:6:in `<main>' EXCEPT
» 12:47:50.130 2013-12-07 11:47:50.075742+00:00 heroku web.1 - - Process exited with status 1
» 12:47:51.142 2013-12-07 11:47:50.088491+00:00 heroku web.1 - - State changed from starting to crashed
» 12:47:53.004 2013-12-07 11:47:42.195734+00:00 heroku web.1 - - State changed from crashed to starting
```

It appears that my app on Heroku still requires the will_paginate gem. How can I find out why?

I tried deploying this app to a new heroku app, which should basically take only the code from my Git and not refer to some previously deployed code/config, but the result is the same.

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# REPLACED BY KAMINARI gem: gem 'will_paginate' #, "~> 2.3.11", :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'meta_search', "~> 1.1.3"
gem 'hirb', "0.5.0"
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'i18n'
gem 'rake', '10.0.3'

# needed for amazon s3
gem 'aws-sdk'

# needed for mysql (cleardb mysql on heroku)
gem 'activerecord-mysql-adapter'
gem 'mysql2'

group :development, :test do

end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'

    # for heroku production
    gem 'thin'  

    gem 'rails_12factor'

end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do

    # to be able to test thin locally
    gem 'foreman'

    gem "hirb", "0.5.0"

    gem 'factory_girl'

    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: Have you tried `heroku run bundle update` in your console? This will run bundler on Heroku, which could resolve it?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a leftover initializer in `/config/initializers/` that references will_paginate.

Comment: Hello, I checked the config/initializers directory locally, but found no references to will_paginate. Do you know if I can check if there's still such an initializer in my app at heroku? Thanks

Comment: Did you commit your changes before pushing them to heroku? The error is definitely referencing an initializer.

Comment: Yes, the latest changes were pushed to github. And these changes were deployed to heroku.
Is there a way to check the contents of the initializers directory on heroku?

Comment: You were right: there was still a file referencing will paginate: app/helpers/remote_link_renderer.rb
It's strange though that this was not causing problems on the development environment where I don't have installed will_paginate either, so that means that this file got only loaded during production? 
Anyway, it's fixed, thanks!

Comment: Development does autoloading - it only loads files when they're needed. If you werent accessing the methods in that file, they would never have been loaded and never errored. Production loads everything at server spinup and keeps it in memory for speed, this may have been why it was only triggered there.